# Proper gunicorn launch

Tags: python, security, gunicorn

I launch gunicorn with commands like `gunicorn -c gunicorn.py main:app`

Content of `gunicorn.py` is:

```
bind = "unix:/tmp/mysock.sock"
workers = 3
backlog = 2048
worker_class = "sync"
#worker_class = "gevent"
debug = False
daemon = True
pidfile = "/tmp/mypid.pid"
logfile = "/tmp/mylog.log"
user = 'www-data' # only under sudo
```

With last line I could not use command above. If I add sudo and launch it like `sudo gunicorn -c gunicorn.py main:app`, master process would run from root, which is bad for security. How to launch properly?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the best way is to run gunicorn under www-data user, with sudo you could do it like this:

```
sudo -u www-data gunicorn -c gunicorn.py main:app
```

to run this command you need either to be root, or to know www-data user password.